# Move points to the main façade

Tags: qgis, postgis, postgresql

How can I move the points to the main façade using Postgis?

I have used the following query

```sql
SELECT ST_ClosestPoint(ln.geom, pt.geom)
FROM "testes"."line1" AS ln
   WHERE ((pt.geom <-> ln.geom) < 0.00019 )
ORDER BY pt.geom <-> ln.geom
LIMIT 1);
```

But the points are moved to the nearest line.

How can I put the roads as a reference, so the dots move to the edge based on the orientation of the main road?

[image: Move points to the main façade]

Comment: Is **"ln"** your road layer ? How is your **"building"** layer structured ? Detecting facades would be a first step and handling every possible case doesn't look that easy imho ...